# Moving to Exchange 2016 while keeping Exchange 2010 as primary relay

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2010

Here's our current setup:
- Firewall with SMTP proxy, scans incoming/outgoing mail and forwards to Exchange2010 server
- Internal Exchange 2010 server (SP3 RU11), running Sophos PureMessage as Exchange AV software

We'd like to upgrade to 2016 in a short time (skipping 2013), however it seems the PureMessage software won't be "certified" for Exchange 2016 somewhere in Q2 of 2016. I don't really want to run it without PureMessage cause it happens sometimes that virus/spam mails still get through our firewall SMTP proxy but then luckily are detected by PureMessage.

So here's my question: Can I leave my Exchange 2010 server in place and keep forwarding mails from the SMTP proxy to 2010, while moving all my mailboxes to my 2016 server, so as to keep my PureMessage checks on incoming mail on the 2010 server and still benefit from the new Exchange 2016 features for Outlook on the web, etc.? I suppose the 2010 server will know to which server it has to deliver the mails?

Thanks a lot for any recommendations.
Michiel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who would be interested here's my follow up:

Exchange 2016 is up and running, all mailboxes are moved from 2010 to 2016.
All web/pop/imap services are directed to the exchange 2016 server and were nicely proxied to the Exchange 2010 server (while the mailboxes where still on 2010)
SMTP is still directed to the 2010 server and mail still gets delivered to the 2016 mailboxes.
I did have to add my Exchange 2016 server to my send connectors manually to be able to send mail to the outside and from 2016 to 2010 mailboxes (incoming mail worked without changes).

Also thanks to Bentek for providing more insight into the proxy-methods in Exchange2016.

Answer (score 1):

Exchange 2016 can co-exist with Exchange 2010/2013 better than previous versions of Exchange; however, I don't believe "up-proxy" from Exchange 2010 CAS -> Mailbox (MBX) on Exchange 2016 will work.

From all the documentation I've seen, it seems **up-proxy** is only supported from 2013 to 2016 and ***not*** 2010 to 2016.

[image]

**Down-proxy** (Exchange 2016 MBX -> Exchange 2010) works just as co-existence worked in an Exchange 2010/2013 environment.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It seems that this is valid for http(s) requests. Is this also for smtp? If I could let smpt go through ex2010 to ex2016 that would be enough. http(s) could go directly to ex2016.